AxiosError: Request failed with status code 500 when sending data from client to database
I am trying to send data from my client-side application to the server using Axios, but I am receiving an error:
AxiosError {message: 'Request failed with status code 500', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_BAD_RESPONSE'}
When I test the same endpoint using Postman, the data is successfully passed to the database without any issues. This suggests that the server and database are functioning correctly, but there might be an issue with the client-side request.
`import React, { useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

    const Signup = () => {
      const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
        fname: "",
        lname: "",
        email: "",
        password: "",
        userType: "customer",
      });
      const navigate=useNavigate()
    
      const handleChange = (e) => {
        setFormData({ ...formData, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
      };
      const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        try {
          const res = await axios.post(
            "http://localhost:5000/api/users/register",
            formData,
            {
              headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
              },
            }
          );
          console.log(res.data);
          setFormData({
            fname: "",
            lname: "",
            email: "",
            password: "",
            userType: "customer",
          });
          if(res.status === 201){
            navigate('/login');
          }
        } catch (error) {
          console.error(error);
        }
      };
      return (
        <div className="flex items-center justify-center min-h-screen bg-gray-100">
          <form
            className="w-full max-w-md bg-white p-8 shadow-md rounded-md"
            onSubmit={handleSubmit}
          >
            <h2 className="text-2xl font-bold text-center mb-6">Sign Up</h2>
    
            <div className="mb-4">
              <label
                htmlFor="fname"
                className="block text-gray-700 font-medium mb-1"
              >
                First Name
              </label>
              <input
                type="text"
                id="fname"
                name="fname"
                value={formData.fname}
                onChange={handleChange}
                className="w-full px-4 py-2 border border-gray-300 rounded-md focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-orange-500"
                required
              />
            </div>
    
            <div className="mb-4">
              <label
                htmlFor="lname"
                className="block text-gray-700 font-medium mb-1"
              >
                Last Name
              </label>
              <input
                type="text"
                id="lname"
                name="lname"
                value={formData.lname}
                onChange={handleChange}
                className="w-full px-4 py-2 border border-gray-300 rounded-md focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-orange-500"
                required
              />
            </div>
    
            <div className="mb-4">
              <label
                htmlFor="email"
                className="block text-gray-700 font-medium mb-1"
              >
                Email
              </label>
              <input
                type="email"
                id="email"
                name="email"
                value={formData.email}
                onChange={handleChange}
                className="w-full px-4 py-2 border border-gray-300 rounded-md focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-orange-500"
                required
              />
            </div>
    
            <div className="mb-6">
              <label
                htmlFor="password"
                className="block text-gray-700 font-medium mb-1"
              >
                Password
              </label>
              <input
                type="password"
                id="password"
                name="password"
                value={formData.password}
                onChange={handleChange}
                className="w-full px-4 py-2 border border-gray-300 rounded-md focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-orange-500"
                required
              />
            </div>
    
            <button
              type="submit"
              className="w-full bg-orange-500 text-white py-2 px-4 rounded-md font-bold hover:bg-orange-600 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-orange-500"
            >
              Sign Up
            </button>
          </form>
        </div>
      );
    };
    
    export default Signup;` `const mongoose = require("mongoose");
    
    const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
      {
        fname: {
          type: String,
          required: true,
        },
        lname: {
          type: String,
          required: true,
        },
        email: {
          type: String,
          required: true,
        },
        password: {
          type: String,
          required: true,
        },
        userType: {
          type: String,
          enum: ["admin", "user"],
          default: "user",
        },
      },
      {
        timestamps: true,
      }
    );
    
    module.exports = mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);` `const express = require("express");
    const router = express.Router();
    const User = require("../../models/User");
    const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");
    const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
    const authenticateToken = require("../../middleware/auth");
    
    //register
    router.post("/register", async (req, res) => {
      try {
        const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
        const password = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, salt);
        const userobj = {
          fname: req.body.fname,
          lname: req.body.lname,
          email: req.body.email,
          password: password,
          userType: req?.body?.userType || "user",
        };
        const user = new User(userobj);
        await user.save();
        return res.status(201).json(user);
      } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json({ message: "Something went wrong" });
      }
    });
    module.exports = router;` `require('dotenv').config()
    const express=require('express');
    const app=express();
    const bodyParser=require("body-parser");
    const cors=require("cors");
    const connectDB=require('./config/db');
    
    
    //parse requests
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.use(express.json());
    app.use(cors());
    
    
    //db
    connectDB();
    
    //routes
    //users route
    app.use('/api/users', require('./routes/api/user'))
    
    //task route
    app.use('/api/task', require('./routes/api/task'))
    
    const port=5000;
    app.listen(port, () =>{
        console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`)
    })`


use browser developer tools to check exactly what the client is sending, compare it with what postman is sending - for example, you set userType: "customer" in the client code, but userType in server code is an enum: ["admin", "user"]

Thank you for pointing that out! The issue was related to a mismatch between the client-side data and the server-side validation. Specifically, I was sending userType: "customer" from the client, but the server expected userType to be one of the enum values: ["admin", "user"], updating the client-side data to send a valid value resolved the issue. I appreciate your help!
